# How to suppress the "Microsoft PDF Reflow has stopped working" error when using python to open pdf file with MS Word?

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, win32com

I was trying to automate the pdf-to-docx process using python.
PDF Reflow will automatically opened if I open pdf files with MS Word. Therefore, I used it as an OCR tool.
I have suppressed the message boxes from Word by using word_app.DisplayAlerts=0 and try-except.
However, message box "Microsoft PDF Reflow has stopped working" still popped out sometimes.

Now I should manually close those message boxes and it is not reasonable for an automated process. Is there anyway to suppress the errors from PDF Reflow?

Below is the code I use:

```
import pythoncom
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
#import logging

word_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")

word_app.Visible = 0
word_app.DisplayAlerts = 0
wc = win32com.client.constants
try:
    word_doc = word_app.Documents.Open('file.pdf')
except pythoncom.com_error as e:
    print(e)
    #logger.info(e)
word_doc.SaveAs(FileName  = 'file.docx', FileFormat = wc.wdFormatXMLDocument)
word_doc.Close(SaveChanges = wc.wdDoNotSaveChanges)

word_app.Quit()
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by myself:

```
import win32com
shell_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
RegKey = r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting'
GetKeyValue = shell_app.RegRead(os.path.join(RegKey, "DontShowUI"))
EditKeyValue = shell_app.RegWrite(os.path.join(RegKey, "DontShowUI"), 1, "REG_DWORD")

##use this to restore your registry
RestoreKeyValue = shell_app.RegWrite(os.path.join(RegKey, "DontShowUI"), GetKeyValue, "REG_DWORD")
```

Be careful when using this code because it edits registry and may damage your computer.

This code is not an ideal solution as it will suppress not only PDF Reflow's error reporting but ALL of them.